# Implementing Montgomery ladder methods for modular exponentiation in python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement the mongomery-ladder method for modular exponentiation for **RSA** (so N=p•q, p,q are primes) in python, as followed in this [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36400-5_22.pdf):
[image: montgomery-ladder pseudo code]

My code looks like this:

- x stands for base, k for exp, and N for modulus

```
# uses montgomery-ladder method for modular exponentiation
def montgomery_ladder(x, k, N):
    x %= N
    k %= N
    # getting the binary representation of k
    bin_k = list(map(int, bin(k)[2:]))
    # Initialize two variables to hold the intermediate results
    r0 = 1
    r1 = x

    # Loop through each bit of the binary exponent from most significant to the least significant
    for i in range(len(bin_k)):
        if bin_k[i] == 0:
            r1 = (r1 * r0) % N
            r0 = (r0 ** 2) % N
        else:
            r0 = (r0 * r1) % N
            r1 = (r1 ** 2) % N

    # The final result is in r0
    return r0
```

it doesn't work well for very large numbers, for example the following test:

```
def main():
    x = 412432421343242134234233
    k = 62243535235312321213254235
    N = 10423451524353243462
    print(montgomery_ladder(x, k, N))
    print(pow(x, k, N))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

yields:

```
7564492758006795519
179467895766154563
```

pow(x, k, n) returns the correct answer, but my function doesn't.
Have any ideas?

Comment: So where do you need the higher power than Charmichael lamda? You tagged RSA, however, the RSA powers are not greater than the Charmichael lamda, and determined during the RSA-KeyGen.

Comment: Also, the tag Montgomery-Multiplication has nothing to do with Montgmomery Ladder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `k %= N` at the start.

Comment: Working example; https://trinket.io/python/ae48dd2263

Comment: @kelalaka Makes no sense to say it's bad for performance when *with* it it's not even correct. You can compare performance of *correct* codes, but comparing performance of a correct code and an incorrect code is nonsense. And about phi: Can you always compute phi(N) quickly? I doubt it.

Comment: Let me write a little more. It really depends on what the size of the power needed and how many times? OP did not say anything about the power size and usage, so I guessed that they somehow needed longer powers than the modulus.

Comment: Otherwise, with the RSA tag, this has nothing since the power in the RSA are determined beforehand they are samaller than Charmichael lambda. So, I was even considering to delete my answer since it doesn't fit RSA case.

Comment: In RSA case, it quite fast since `phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1)`, even it will be faster than any library. Of course, this requires the knowledge of the factor and not possible if you are encryption, usually small `e`is used and factorization is not known, or no need in the signature generation and verifier has not access the factor or lambda.

Comment: @kelalaka But to implement rsa I need to do modular exponentiation, and i read that the montgomery ladder algorithm is secure for it… Im sorry for poor knowledge in this area

Comment: https://cse.buffalo.edu/srds2009/escs2009_submission_Gopal.pdf

Comment: I prefer this answer because it hews more closely to the question. The question refers specifically to modular exponentiation but does not state that it's exclusively about RSA *private key* operations. This answer works for public key operations and private key operations including blinding operations.